# How do I add class instance to list/vector in chai script?

Tags: c++, chaiscript

How can i put an instance of a sprite in a list in chaiscript like this:

```
global Vaxskivling = Sprite("/resources/textures/Vaxskivling.png");
var list = [Vaxskivling];
```

When doing this i receive the following error:

*Error: "Can not find appropriate 'clone' or copy constructor for vector elements*

i have added the class constructor and type:

```
    chai->add(chaiscript::base_class<Renderable, Sprite>());
    chai->add(chaiscript::user_type<Sprite>(), "Sprite");
```

Comment: Did you try to add copy constructor explicitly, like [in this example](https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/blob/develop/cheatsheet.md#constructors)?

Comment: Thanks pptaszni your comment plus this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938907/error-using-defaulted-copy-constructor-deleted-function lead me to a solution. I had to change unique_ptr to shared_ptr in my interface.

Answer (score 0):

I had a unique_ptr reference in my interface "Renderable" which Sprite implements. I changed to shared_ptr plus using this constructor:

chai.add(chaiscript::constructor<MyType (const MyType &)>(), "MyType");

my issue was resolved!